# Visual Studio windows layout presets

Tags: visual-studio, layout

I want to be able to store/load Visual Studio layout presets.
I.e. I have a laptop I work at with 1366x768 resolution. When I put it into the dock station I have a 1600x1200 display attached. I want to have a Visual Studio layout preset for each resolution.

I want to be able to switch Visual Studio windows layouts easily. Is there any addin available to fulfill my needs?

#### See also

> [Can I save the window layout in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736754/can-i-save-the-window-layout-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I was able to find the answer here at StackOverflow. The addin name is Perspectives and it can be found in Visual Studio online gallery.

> [Can I save the window layout in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736754/can-i-save-the-window-layout-in-visual-studio-2010)