# How to quickly switch windows layout in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

When I'm developing an UI interface of WinForms app I need toolbox panel and some other panels. But when I'm on writing the code itself basically I don't need everything unless two code windows. How can I set up this layouts and then just switching between them by pressing some hotkeys?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I save the window layout in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736754/can-i-save-the-window-layout-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need are `Perspectives'.
A perspective is a current configuration including toolbars, docked panels etc.
You can consider the '[Perspectives](http://perspectives.codeplex.com/)' add-in for Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Shift + Alt + Enter toggles full screen mode. Other useful shortcuts can be found [here](http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx#window).