# Weird window layout behavior of Visual Studio 2008 and 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am experiencing a weird behavior of visual studio 2008 and VS 2010. I had only Visual Studio 2008 on my machine having OS windows Server 2008 R2, at point i did some window layout reset and post that visual studio's window layout is acting strange, it is getting docked or un-docked if i debug a solution. I re-install the visual studio 2008 but problem still exists...Strangely i have newly installed Visual 2010 pro and it seems to have the same issue. I am wondering which system file got corrupted and y it is only with Visual Studios. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior, actually, for all versions of Visual Studio. There is nothing wrong with your computer or your installation.

Visual Studio has at least two different window layout *modes*. One of them is the **design-time mode**, and the other one is the **debugging mode**.

When you start debugging, the environment switches to the debug mode. In the default configuration, that *will* cause windows to rearrange themselves (some that were hidden appear, some that were visible disappear, others just change position). into a layout that is deemed "optimal" for debugging code.

The idea is that different window layouts are likely to be optimal for different purposes. In design mode, I might want the Toolbox and Properties windows to be visible. I don't need those at all in debug mode, and would rather devote my screen space to the Immediate, Output, and Auto Variables windows instead.

It can be confusing, because you have to rearrange your windows twice, once for each mode. The good news is that any changes you make will "stick", meaning that they will be saved and re-used each time you enter that mode.

If you really don't like it, just arrange your environment so that it is identical in both modes.

<sub>Related: [Can I save the window layout in Visual Studio 2010/2012/2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736754/can-i-save-the-window-layout-in-visual-studio-2010-2012-2013)</sub>

Comment: First thanks for the information. However the problem is that even when i stick it, the next time when i debug it is back to its previous un-docked mode. It is not getting fixed. :(

Comment: Also if i do import and export windows layout setting it gives me mentioned below error:Your settings were imported, but there were some errors.

Error 1:  An error occurred while importing settings for 'Window Layouts'.